# Why codeigniter display double quote(empty) on top page

Tags: codeigniter

I use codeigniter framework, run on chrome but display double quote on top page.

[image]

My controller call view page.

```
public function index(){
$this->load->view('dash_main');    
}
```

dash_main.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    Hello World 
</body>
</html>
```

How can i edit?

Comment: Are you sure that screen shot is of the output from this file? The `<title>` should be in `<head>`, and there's no explanation for those `<html>` tag attributes.

Comment: Note, Chrome and some other browsers tend to try and fix broken code, they also have there means of displaying said code back in the consoles. As there way of trying to map everything to whatever its coming from for your debugging needs. So in all, what you see in the console debug view is not likely always rendered in the actual view source, and chances are your over thinking something. Is your site actually malfunctioning from this, or did it happen to catch your eye while debugging and now your curious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make sure that your file (view) has been saved to UTF-8 format.
  I got the same problem as you, just change file to utf-8 format. that's all ^^

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't in your source code, it's just what the Chrome inspector shows around text. Nothing to do with Codeigniter, nothing to do with your code or HTML output.

View the actual page source and you won't see any quotes (but you will see a lot of white space judging from your screen shot).

Comment: I can fix it.
Save utf-8 with out BOM at all file